# Adding a new associative element to a JSON object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

i have the problem to add elements to an json array.

The structure i want is that:

```
[{"method":"edit","type":"1", "template":"3", "meta":{"title":"Tools", "descirption":"Tools"}}]
```

The problem is that i add all these parameters dynamically.

So lets say i have for the start:

```
[{"method":"edit","type":"1", "template":"3"}]
```

How can i add the whole "meta" array and please do not be with push(), because than i will have another structure when i print it.

When i use

`$json = json_decode($json, true);`

I want to have:

```
array(
    method' => edit,
    'type' => 1,
    'template' => 3,
    'meta' => array('title' => '')
);
```

Thanks in advice !

Comment: If you want to do it on server side, use  array_merge

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to assume you have the JSON to start with. So let's decode to PHP (as you noted correctly)

```
$json = json_decode($json, true);
```

So now we should have `$json['method']`, etc. Now let's define `$meta`

```
$meta = array('title' => '');
```

And add this to `$json`

```
$json['meta'] = $meta;
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 0):

When your current JSON decodes in PHP using `json_decode`, it will decode into an array with one element, or `array[0]`. Therefore in order to access or any object you need to first point to that `0` index. Do it this way:

```
$json = '[{"method":"edit","type":"1", "template":"3"}]';

$arr = json_decode($json);
$arr[0]->meta = array('title' => '');
$json = json_encode($arr);

var_dump($json);
//Result:
// string '[{"method":"edit","type":"1","template":"3","meta":{"title":""}}]' (length=65)
```